# Can I use USB Dongle to connect Raspberry PI to internet?

Tags: debian, usb, wireless

I have the **Type B model** Raspberry PI and I'm using **Debian Wheezy**. And I want to know if I can attach my USB dongle to the board.

I have [searched for support](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals), but I haven't found my model listed. My USB dongle is:

1. MF 190 (ZTE corp)
2. MMX353G (Micromax) (this one is second donge; [more details](http://www.micromaxinfo.com/data-card/3G/MMX%20353G))

If possible, how do I install the necessary drivers?

When I insert MMX353G (Micromax) Dongle to it (along with Keyboard); and enter the command `lsusb` the output is:

```
Bus 001 Device 001 : ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 001 : ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystem corp.
Bus 001 Device 001 : ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystem corp.
Bus 001 Device 001 : ID 1c9e:f000 OMEGA TECHNOLoGY
Bus 001 Device 001 : ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Bussiness
```

Comment: To use a GSM modem on the Pi, I have had good experience with the [Sakis3G](http://www.sakis3g.org/) script. See this [guide](http://shkspr.mobi/blog/2012/07/3g-internet-on-raspberry-pi-success/), and note that the Pi might not supply enough power so that a powered USB hub is required. I posted about my setup [here](http://itsacleanmachine.blogspot.fi/2012/11/raspberry-router.html).

Comment: @Alex Chamberlain You have edited a lot, now please solve.
So, I have got vendor name, product id. Now what should I have to do?
Should I have to use *sudo apt-get* cmnd? Tell me the procedure.

Comment: Actually, @Caleb edited a lot; I just approved and added a minor edit. Generally, search the vendors website.

Comment: Being demanding isn't going to help you. I don't have the expertise to solve it for you so demanding that I do so isn't going to help at all. What I can and did do for you is contribute edits with proper English and formatting cleanup so that your question is more readable and bearable to an expert to wade through when one comes along that could solve your issue. You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I [wrote a guide](http://bigcowpi.blogspot.com/2013/03/raspberry-pi-as-3g-huawei-e303-wireless.html) to using Sakis3g and a Huawei E303 dongle to provide internet on the Pi. It takes you through how to get usb_modeswitch running too - I had to do some research to get the correct information for usb_modeswitch.conf :)

I realise you are using a different dongle, but the principle is the same and I imagine it will set you on the right path.

Comment: Hi, can we use wifi dongle without any external usb power hub? That's my project requirement to use the dongle without any external power source! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sakis3G website was down for some time but is now back.

Visit the download page [here](http://www.sakis3g.org/) and run it on your RPi using

```
./sakis3g --interactive
```

You may need to try several times because the script will ask on which "port" the modem is.

Once you'll have the right parameters, you should be able to script the sakis3g using ./sakis3g start. If it does not work at first time, it will help you to provide the right arguments according to the right parameters.

Also, you will most probably need a powered USB HUB because 3G modems need a lot of electrical power to work, and RPi does not have enough (you will see it at once, the RPi will reboot in this case).

Be sure your carrier network is available, I had some issues because of this.

If this does not work, you also can follow the instructions given [here](http://wiki.debian.org/Modem/3G) but also can find some useful information [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_3G_Modem) (even if it is a page for ArchLinux, not Debian).

If you need to configure it manually, below is the wvdial.conf I configured for a friend on its RPi:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB3
Dial Attempts = 1
Dial Command = ATM0L0DT
Baud = 460800
Modem Type = USB Modem
Check Def Route = on
Abort on busy = off
Abort On No Dialtone = on
Ask Password = off
Init = ATZ
Username = websfr
Password = websfr
Phone = *99***1#
;Phone = *99#
Init1 = ATZ 
Init2 = AT+cgdcont=,"IP","websfr"
Init3 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Auto Reconnect = on
ISDN = off
Auto DNS = on
Carrier on check = off
Idle Seconds = 1000
Stupid mode = off
```

Replace 'websfr' and phone number with information from your carrier.

Replace /dev/ttyUSB3 with /dev/ttyUSBx (x can vary according to your modem, you'll have to try it).

And [here](http://pkgs.org/debian-squeeze/debian-backports-main-i386/usb-modeswitch-data_20120815-2~bpo60+1_all.deb.html) is a package that contains information to help using usb-modeswitch.

You may also need to reset your usb device sometimes. Instead of rebooting, you can use the [tool given there](http://www.clearchain.com/blog/posts/resetting-the-usb-bus-under-linux) to do this (you'll need to compile but instructions are straightforward).

Answer (score 0):

For a complete guide to connect the Raspberry PI via a USB 3G Modem without Sakis3G have a look at :  [How to setup a USB 3G Modem on Raspberry PI using usb_modeswitch and wvdial](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-setup-usb-3g-modem-raspberry-pi-using-usbmodeswitch-and-wvdial)

Comment: You should summarise that post in your answer and use that link as a reference, OR leave that link as a comment. If that link stops working, your answer will become void.